# can we use owl:SameAs between two predicates?

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl

What is the difference between using `<DC:title> <owl:SameAs> <NS:title>` and `<DC:title> <owl:equivalentProperty> <NS:title>`

Here NS is some namespace.

Answer (score 11):

`owl:sameAs` is intended for individuals, `owl:equivalentProperty` is intended for RDFS/OWL properties, and `owl:equivalentClass` is intended for RDFS/OWL classes.

I guess you're stating equivalence between these properties so that you can infer

```
:individual1 ns:title "The Title".
```

from an existing statement

```
:individual1 dc:title "The Title".
```

or vice versa. I haven't tried this, but I'd assume that DL-based OWL reasoners (that is, most OWL reasoners) will only do the appropriate inference if `owl:equivalentProperty` is used. On the other hand, if you wanted to infer

```
:individual2 dc:title "The Title".
```

from an existing statement

```
:individual1 dc:title "The Title".
```

then you should use an `owl:sameAs` statement to relate the two individuals.

Comment: I completely agree with your statement, but my point is , since we can use sameAs for any types of resources and predicate is also a type of resource, so is it technically correct to use sameAs for predicates.

Comment: No. `owl:sameAs` is for equivalence of *invidivuals*. It is *not* for “any kind of resource”. If you want reasoning to work, you'll have to use `owl:equivalentProperty`.

Comment: In OWL 1, it says the following about equivalentProperty:

"Property equivalence is not the same as property equality. ... Property equality should be expressed with the owl:sameAs construct."

It's hard for me to determine, did this changed in OWL 2?

Answer (score 8):

Two differences:

Firstly some OWL reasoners will object to `owl:sameAs` between properties, or simply ignore it. They maintain strong distinction between individuals and classes / properties.

Secondly (and this is more significant) equivalence (like `owl:equivalentProperty`) is not the same as identity (`owl:sameAs`). The latter says that we are dealing with one thing with different names, whereas the former says that there are two things which have the same extension (that is, hold between the same things).

If that's not clear here's an example:

```
# My book has ns:title "My book"
:book ns:title "My book" .

# My title property is defined in my vocabulary document
ns:title rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://example.com/my-vocab> .
```

Using `owl:sameAs` my book also has `dc:title` "My book" and `dc:title` is defined by my vocabulary document. Oops, DC may not be happy about that.

With `owl:equivalentProperty` my book also has `dc:title` "My book" (great), but it doesn't imply that `dc:title` is defined by vocabulary document (phew).

Comment: I don't think reasoners will object, they'll infer that the properties are individuals as well and hence will fall into OWL-Full, which you don't really want.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no, don't do this" as explained in [cygris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7075542/1260887). There is, however, more subtlety in the question if you really want to know the implications of using `owl:sameAs` VS. `owl:equivalentProperty`.

First, a little correction about the terms in the question: In RDF, a *predicate* is something that is in the second position of a triple. RDF have no way of referring to positions in triples, so you cannot use a property between two predicates. What is certainly meant by the OP is "can we use `owl:sameAs` between two *properties*". Properties can be identified with IRIs, IRIs can occur anywhere in a triple, subject and object can be related by way of a predicate, and any IRI are allowed in any position of a triple. So, syntactically speaking, it is allowed to relate two properties with `owl:sameAs`.

The question is, though, whether it makes sense to do so, and what the implications are. The issue is that there is something quantumdesque about RDF graphs: the meaning of an RDF graph is a superposition of meanings, and you only know the observable meaning when you apply some reasoning according to some formal semantics. [RDF 1.1 Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-mt-20140225/) defines multiple semantics (so-called *entailment regimes*) but none of them gives a specific meaning to `owl:sameAs`, so applying RDF(S) reasoning wouldn't bring anything useful. Consequently, if such is the observed meaning of the graph, `owl:sameAs` between properties is useless.

The real interesting things arise when one applies OWL semantics. But even in OWL, there is a duality of meanings with the [OWL 2 Directed Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-direct-semantics-20121211/) and the [OWL 2 RDF-based Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-rdf-based-semantics-20121211/). Let us consider an example RDF graph:

```
<p>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:creator  "AZ" .
<q>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:date  "2016-06-07"^^xsd:date  .
<r>  a  owl:ObjectProperty, owl:DeprecatedProperty;
     dc:date  "1981-01-14"^^xsd:date .
<s>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:date  "2016-06-07"^^xsd:date .
<p>  owl:sameAs  <q> .
<r>  owl:equivalentProperty  <s>
<a>  <p>  <b> .
<c>  <r>  <d> .
```

Let us start with the RDF-based semantics. On the one hand, IRIs `<r>` and `<s>` denote *equivalent properties*, so we can conclude:

```
<c>  <s>  <d> .
```

On the other hand, IRIs `<p>` and `<q>` name *the same resource*, so we can conclude that (among other things):

```
<q>  dc:creator  "AZ" .
<p>  dc:date  "2016-06-07"^^xsd:date .
<a>  <q>  <b> .
<p>  owl:equivalentClass  <q> .
```

The difference is that everything one says about `<p>` holds for `<q>` because it is the same! In general, different property names refer to different properties, because they must be attached to different metadata (such as `rdfs:isDefinedBy`, `rdfs:label`, `rdfs:comment`, DC terms).

Let us now apply the Direct Semantics to this. It fails. The Direct Semantics does not apply to RDF graphs, it applies to ontologies in the functional-style syntax of the [OWL 2 Structural Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/). In order to interpret an RDF graph according to the Direct Semantics, one has first to map the graph to an OWL 2 ontology in the functional syntax. This requires that the RDF graph satisfies some constraints, in order to be an *OWL 2 Ontology in RDF graph form*.

One obligation is that all individuals have to be explicitly declared as members of some OWL classes. Another requirement is that `owl:sameAs` can only apply to individuals. Individuals are strictly disjoint from properties, but there is a little trick: an individual *name* can be the same as a property *name* (this is called [*punning*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-new-features-20121211/#F12:_Punning)). All properties must be declared as either object properties, datatype properties, or annotation properties. A name must be given to the ontology, together with a statement that explicitly says that it is an ontology. So, a version of the RDF graph that is a valid OWL 2 Ontology in RDF graph form is as follows:

```
<>  a  owl:Ontology .  # Give a name to the ontology and declare it as such
dc:creator  a  owl:AnnotationProperty .  # Declare property
dc:date  a  owl:Annotation Property .  # Declare property
<p>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:creator  "AZ" .
<q>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:date  "2016-06-07"^^xsd:date  .
<r>  a  owl:ObjectProperty, owl:DeprecatedProperty;
     dc:date  "1981-01-14"^^xsd:date .
<s>  a  owl:ObjectProperty;
     dc:date  "2016-06-07"^^xsd:date .
<p>  a  owl:Thing .  # <p> used with owl:sameAs: must be declared as individual
<q>  a  owl:Thing .  # <q> used with owl:sameAs: must be declared as individual
<a>  a  owl:Thing .  # Declare individual
<b>  a  owl:Thing .  # Declare individual
<c>  a  owl:Thing .  # Declare individual
<d>  a  owl:Thing .  # Declare individual
<p>  owl:sameAs  <q> .
<r>  owl:equivalentProperty  <s>
<a>  <p>  <b> .
<c>  <r>  <d> .
```

On this graph, we can apply the OWL 2 Direct Semantics, with which we can conclude:

```
<c>  <s>  <d> .
```

None of the other triples given before with the RDF-based Semantics can be inferred. In particular, the fact the `<p>` and `<q>` denote the same individual does not allow to conclude anything about the properties named `<p>` and `<q>`.

Again, in this case, it's usually not a good idea to use `owl:sameAs`.

In conclusion, however you interpret the RDF graph, using `owl:sameAs` to relate two properties is likely not a good idea.